# Simple Form label_method for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a form using slim/simple_form.

```
= f.association :users,
  collection: @users,
  prompt: "Choose Recipient",
  label_method: :first_name
```

I would like to have the user's full name as the label method, could someone point me in the right direction? I only have first_name and last_name as attributes. I will also prefer to add  the user's company name next to their full name for clarity in selection. Does simple form allow this? else I will retreat to options from collection for select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method on your model:

```
class User < ArcitveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

and use it:

```
= f.association :users,
  collection: @users,
  prompt: "Choose Recipient",
  label_method: :full_name
```

Comment: I actually already had it in the model. Silly me didn't think to use it, I thought only database attributes were usable

Answer (score 1):

If you like to prefer adding `company_name` next to the `full_name`,I would just modify **Broisatse's** answer as

```
class User < ArcitveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def full_name_with_company_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name} #{company_name}"
  end
end
```

and use it:

```
= f.association :users,
  collection: @users,
  prompt: "Choose Recipient",
  label_method: :full_name_with_company_name
```